# Capturar respuesta del servidor mediante ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Buen dia, tengo un ajax que va y consulta algo y de acuerdo a la consulta me devuelve en un echo $tipo_de_solicitud; una variable la cual ya se que lo hace bien por que lo compruebo por el inspector de chrome (F12), la cuestion es al recibirla en el ajax y querer hacer algo dependiendo de lo que se haya respondido alla en el .php

aqui el ajax

```
function confirmar_visita2(boton2)
{

  let id = boton2.value;

  var confirmar_visita = confirm("Confirmar visita para solicitud #"+id);

  if (confirmar_visita == true)
  {
    //recogo valores fecha hora y tecnico asignado
    var fecha=$('#input_fecha_visita').val();
    var hora=$('#input_hora_visita').val();

    var selector = document.getElementById("select_tecnico_para_visita");
    var tecnico_escogido = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].text;

    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('id',id);
    data.append('fecha',fecha);
    data.append('hora',hora);
    data.append('tecnico_escogido',tecnico_escogido);

    //envio al php

    var url = '../PHP/confirmar_visita_solicitud_revision_tecnica.php';
    $.ajax
    ({
      url:url,
      type:'POST',
      contentType:false,
      data:data,
      processData:false,
      cache:false,
      beforeSend: function(resp)
      {
        $("#span_estado").html("cargando...");
      },
      success: function()
      {
        //aqui el problema, he intentado sin el .trim, me dice exactamente que no pue
        var respuesta=this.responseText();

// aqui hago algo dependiendo de la respuesta, como he dicho eso funciona bien en el php
        if(respuesta=='revision_tecnica')
        {
          consultar_solicitudes_revision_tecnica();
        }

        if(respuesta=='instalacion')
        {
          consultar_solicitudes_revision_tecnica();
        }
        //borro campos por si se necesita despues para confirmar otra solicitud
        $('#input_hora_visita').val('');
        $('#input_fecha_visita').val('');
      }
    });
  }
  if (confirmar_visita == false)
  {
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La funcion `success` recibe un parametro de respuesta, intentalo asi:

```
$.ajax
    ({
      url:url,
      type:'POST',
      contentType:false,
      data:data,
      processData:false,
      cache:false,
      beforeSend: function(resp)
      {
        $("#span_estado").html("cargando...");
      },
      success: function(respuesta)
      {                
// aqui hago algo dependiendo de la respuesta, como he dicho eso funciona bien en el php
        if(respuesta=='revision_tecnica')
        {
          consultar_solicitudes_revision_tecnica();
        }

        if(respuesta=='instalacion')
        {
          consultar_solicitudes_revision_tecnica();
        }
        //borro campos por si se necesita despues para confirmar otra solicitud
        $('#input_hora_visita').val('');
        $('#input_fecha_visita').val('');
      }
    });
```

Comment: perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba, gracias!